# Search the document library using rest api in Sharepoint including its content

Tags: javascript, managed-metadata, custom, sharepoint-rest-api, json

I dont require sharepoint search answers.I require using JS/Json/Web service/rest api.If i type anything in search box in top nav it should go to another page and show the results.Is there any way to do that using the above requirement.

Edit:I got all the results from single document library using below link code http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/calling-sharepoint-search-using-rest-eg.html Based on managed metadata column in my document library i want to display the data.Is it possible?

Comment: In the first paragraph you have mentioned you are searching using the OOB Seach Box(i presume). So why do you need the REST API implementation as mentioned in the second paragraph ?  Can you please elaborate the requirement ?

Comment: i want to retrieve all the value from document library including its content.(In OOTB search i am not getting all the column value of the library)So i want custom search?There is any way to Do that

Comment: OK. Getting search results in possible using REST as well as JSOM. Once you have retrieved all the results,how do you want to conditionally format/display using managed metadata ?

Comment: Yeah.I tried to get the values but the managed metadata values are not there in JSON format results obtained

Comment: Please map the crawled properties to managed properties and do full crawl. If you don't have mapping then you can't get the results in rest response. Also in managed properties you need to check whether it's searchable, query able, faceted etc. So it should mostly help you to get the desired results.

Comment: Yeah you right  i had not mapped the properties.Now i did that and the search is working fine.Thanks